How to fill an array that created in the main function in a void function with Pointers?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void add_numbers_to_array (int *array);

int main() {
    int array1[] {};
    int array2[] {};

    cout << array1 << endl;
    cout << "PLEASE ADD INTEGER NUMBERS TO THE ARRAY1" << endl;
    add_numbers_to_array(array1);

    cout << array2 << endl;
    cout << "PLEASE ADD INTEGER NUMBERS TO THE ARRAY2" << endl;
    add_numbers_to_array(array2);
    
    unsigned array1_size = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]);
    unsigned array2_size = sizeof(array2) / sizeof(array2[0]);

    cout << array1[0] << array1_size << endl;
    cout << array2[0] << array2_size << endl;

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

void add_numbers_to_array (int *array) {
    unsigned numberfor_arraysize {0};
    cout << "HOW MANY NUMBERS DO YOU WANT TO ADD: ";
    cin >> numberfor_arraysize;

    for (unsigned i=0 ; i<numberfor_arraysize ; i++) {
        int number {0};
        cout << "\nPLEASE ADD THE NUMBER " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> number;

        *(array+i) = number;
        cout << number << " HAS BEEN ADDED TO ARRAY. LOCATION: " << array+i << " => " << *(array+i) << endl;
    }
}

Hi, I'm new to programming and I'm learning pointers at this moment. While I was trying to do a challange section I'm stuck and I don't understand what am I doing wrong? What am I missing here?
In the main function, I declared two arrays named array1 and array2. I wanted to appoint integers with user inputs. So I created a function called add_numbers_to_array and in the function parameter, I declared array as a pointer to an integer. I used pointer cause I wanted to change the actual array in the main function and not create a copy.
Then, in the main fuction, I called add_numbers_to_array function with address of the array. And in the void function, I asked "How many numbers you wish to add", and then I looped for that amount of numbers. And each itteration, user inputs a number that will be appoint to the pointer array with assignment operator.
So everything works till here exactly the way that I wanted. Cause I can see it. But when the void function terminates and we go back to main function, I can't see the numbers in the array that user input. Where am I doing wrong here? What am I missing/can't see/ don't understand?

C arrays can't be extended (or reduced). std::vector would be more appropriate.

It's more a lucky coincidence, that your program doesn't crash because with *(array+i) = number; you may be accessing memory that isn't allocated by your process ...

@derpirscher unlucky coincidence. Loudly failing as soon as you try it is one of the safest manifestations of undefined behaviour

int array1[] {}; is not valid standard C++. Is int arr[ ] valid C++?

How is array1[0] supposed to work when the array had no size at the time of its definitinon.
